# Pentaho File Repository Moves Jobs & Transformations to root

Tags: import, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I created a new file repository, and then *moved* my [pentaho](/questions/tagged/pentaho) project files into the root folder using a file manager. I then connected to my file repository and opened(<kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>) my job & transformation files(in a `folder/`), then tried to run them, which threw the error below:

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: 
Unable to load the job from XML file [F:/user/root/job.kjb]

Unable to read file [file:///F:/user/root/job.kjb]
Could not read from "file:///F:/user/root/job.kjb" because it is not a file.


    at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.<init>(JobMeta.java:738)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.<init>(JobMeta.java:710)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.<init>(JobMeta.java:685)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.filerep.KettleFileRepository.loadJob(KettleFileRepository.java:949)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.job.JobGraph.startJob(JobGraph.java:3466)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonJobDelegate.executeJob(SpoonJobDelegate.java:1403)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.executeJob(Spoon.java:8486)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.executeFile(Spoon.java:8445)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.runFile(Spoon.java:8410)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1366)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7984)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9245)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:692)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: 
Unable to read file [file:///F:/user/root/job.kjb]
Could not read from "file:///F:/user/root/job.kjb" because it is not a file.

    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:561)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:540)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.<init>(JobMeta.java:726)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileNotFoundException: Could not read from "file:///F:/user/root/job.kjb" because it is not a file.
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getInputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1309)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.DefaultFileContent.getInputStream(DefaultFileContent.java:411)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getInputStream(KettleVFS.java:270)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:559)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\user\root\job.kjb (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.local.LocalFile.doGetInputStream(LocalFile.java:241)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getInputStream(AbstractFileObject.java:1301)
    ... 40 more
```

I then saved(<kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>) the file(s) and then they ran, however, they were also *moved* to the `root/` from `root/folder`. Why & How to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using ***Save As...*** option and save the files in place as opposed to ***Save*** as that for some reason saves them(in fact even moves them) to `root` even though I was given the option to select them in the open menu provided by the repository itself, in the `folder` where I've first put them in.